# Problem In covering Account Team Member

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

***Followed Approaches:***

Approach1:

- I have created test users and Tried it,but still account team member isnot covering

Approach2:

- If I tried for currently Logged in user  below issue is present

[INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY in test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240400/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-in-test-class)

---

```
   public static string saveCcrRecord(CCR__c record,string ccrtype){
    string result='test';
    User loggedInUser = [Select id,contactId,Contact.AccountId from User 
  where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
  string partnerco = loggedInUser.Contact.AccountId;
  //below Line isnot covering accTeamMember shows null values
   List<AccountTeamMember>  accTeamMember = [SELECT AccountId,Id,TeamMemberRole,UserId,User.Email,User.Name,User.Phone FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE
                                              AccountId =:partnerco AND TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer' LIMIT 1];
    if(accTeamMember.size()>0)   {
        record.Partner_SE_Name__c = accTeamMember[0].User.name;
        if(!string.isBlank(accTeamMember[0].User.email))
            record.Partner_SE_Email__c = accTeamMember[0].User.email;
        if(!string.isBlank(accTeamMember[0].User.Phone))
            record.Partner_SE_Phone__c = accTeamMember[0].User.Phone;

      //code

    return result;
}
```

}

In test class:

```
 public static testmethod void IncentiveController(){

    Id accountRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Partner/Distributor').getRecordTypeId();
    Account ac=new Account();
    ac.Name='Test Account';
    ac.RecordTypeId=accountRecordTypeId;
    insert ac;

    contact ct=new contact();
    ct.lastName='contact';
    ct.accountid=ac.id;
    ct.email='newEmail@gmail.com';
    ct.phone='8147285030';
    insert ct;

    Id ccRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.CCR__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Partner Claim Form').getRecordTypeId();
    CCR__c Cr=new CCR__c();
    Cr.recordtypeId=ccRecordTypeId;
    Incentives__c incent=new Incentives__c();
    incent.CCR_Type__c='Brik_Dollar_Incentive_Claim_Req';
    insert incent;
    string Id=incent.id;

    Id p = [select id from profile where name='Partner Community User'].id;

    User user = new User(alias = 'user123', email='user123@noemail.com',
                         emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='users', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                         localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p, country='United States',IsActive =true,
                         ContactId = ct.Id,
                         timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='tester@noemail.com');

    insert user;

        accountteammember atm= new accountteammember();
        atm.AccountId=ac.id;
        atm.userid=user.id;
        atm.teammemberrole='Sales Engineer';
        insert atm;
     PC_IncentiveController.saveCcrRecord(Cr,'Marketing SPIFF');   

  }
```

Comment: Please note that use of all caps is often interpreted as yelling and quite rude.

Comment: Isn't this really the same as [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240400/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-in-test-class)? I think there was a misunderstanding regarding my suggestion there; I will go back and try to clarify.

Comment: same question only david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me!!!

```
   @isTest
    public static testmethod void testSaveCcrRecord(){
    User u = [Select ID From User where id = :userInfo.getUserID()];
    User portalUser;
    system.runAs(u){
        portalUser = createPartnerUser();
    }
    Id ccRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.CCR__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Partner Claim Form').getRecordTypeId();
    CCR__c Cr=new CCR__c();
    Cr.recordtypeId=ccRecordTypeId;
    system.runAs(portalUser){
        PC_IncentiveController.saveCcrRecord(Cr,'Marketing SPIFF'); 
    }

}   

private static User createPartnerUser(){
    Id accountRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Partner/Distributor').getRecordTypeId();
    Account ac=new Account();
    ac.Name='Test Account';
    ac.RecordTypeId=accountRecordTypeId;
    insert ac;
    contact ct=new contact();
    ct.lastName='contact';
    ct.accountid=ac.id;
    ct.email='newEmail@gmail.com';
    ct.phone='8147285030';
    insert ct;
    Id ccRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.CCR__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Partner Claim Form').getRecordTypeId();
    CCR__c Cr=new CCR__c();
    Cr.recordtypeId=ccRecordTypeId;
    Incentives__c incent=new Incentives__c();
    incent.CCR_Type__c='Brik_Dollar_Incentive_Claim_Req';
    insert incent;
    string Id=incent.id;
    Id p = [select id from profile where name='Partner Community User'].id;
    User user = new User(alias = 'user123', email='user123@noemail.com',
                         emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='users', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                         localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p, country='United States',IsActive =true,
                         ContactId = ct.Id,
                         timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='tester@noemail.com');
    insert user;
    accountteammember atm= new accountteammember();
    atm.AccountId=ac.id;
    atm.userid=user.id;
    atm.teammemberrole='Sales Engineer';
    insert atm;
    return user;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As `saveCcrRecord1()` queries the logged in user and trying to populate `AccountTeamMember` information based on related to `Contact.AccountId`

```
User loggedInUser = [Select id,contactId,Contact.AccountId from User where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];

string partnerco = loggedInUser.Contact.AccountId;
record.Partner_Company_Name__c=partnerco;
record.CCR_Type__c = ccrtype;
List<AccountTeamMember> accTeamMember = [SELECT AccountId,Id,TeamMemberRole,UserId,User.email,User.Name,User.Phone FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE
                                         AccountId =:partnerco AND TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer' LIMIT 1];
```

So, in the test method, use `System.runsAs(user)` to execute below script like this:

```
System.runsAs(user)
{
    accountteammember atm= new accountteammember();
    atm.AccountId=ac.id;
    atm.userid=user.id;
    atm.teammemberrole='Sales Engineer';
    insert atm;
    PC_IncentiveController.saveCcrRecord1(Cr,'Marketing SPIFF');
}
```

Comment: It's not working .

Comment: did you debug properly, what is not working?

Comment: I have logged in as system.runAs(Userinfo.getUserId)  also..but itsnot working

Comment: Is that still taking SystemAdmin user?

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: You didn't follow my answer, instead of writing `system.runAs(new user(ID = UserInfo.getUserID()))` you should write `system.runAs(user)`, then only code will execute based on the user created. Make sense?

Comment: i have tried that.It causes one more issue.Owd is priavte for account

Comment: Then better create all the records within `System.runAs(user)` block. First create user and then create rest of the account, contact etc.

Comment: but he is partner user. I need contact ID while creating user